# Verb Sitzen Im Perfekt

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Does the verb *sitzen* require *haben* or *sein* in the perfect?

Comment: You can always look stuff like this up. If your have basic understanding of the language, duden.de is a great source and there you would a have found "[ich habe (süddeutsch, österreichisch, schweizerisch: bin) gesessen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sitzen)". If understanding is more of an issue, there are sites that are more reduced to the grammar: "[sitzt · saß · hat gesessen](https://www.verbformen.de/konjugation/sitzen.htm)".

Answer (score 5):

In Standard German, *haben* is used as auxiliary verb. In some High German dialects and often in the High German language area in general, however, *sein* is used.

Comment: Right, although in Austria "gesessen sein" isn't even considered dialectal, but Standard Austrian.

Comment: @Same for South Germany, confirmed by grammar *Pons, Die Deutsche Grammatik*.

Comment: And in Bavaria, *er hat gesessen* invariably means *he was in jail*

Comment: @Jan I think that applies for all of southern Germany. I almost wrote an answer that "ist gesessen" is correct, because "hat gesessen" means jail to me. I'm Swabian.

Comment: I agree with this and referred to this fact by *often in the High German language area in general*. Of course Swabia, Bavaria, the rest of southern Germany and Austria belong to it.